# XML schema error - root element of a w3c xml schema

Tags: xml, visual-studio, ssis, wsdl, schema

I'm trying to add a web service task via [[Visual Studio 2010 Shell for SQL Server 2012 SSIS]].

I have the wsdl file and the xsd file in the same folder. When I try to reference the wsdl file below, I get the error from Visual Studio:

**The root element of a W3C XML Schema should be `<schema>` and its namespace should be 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'.**

Here are the first few lines of the 13,000 line wsdl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:s0="http://www.cisco.com/AXLAPIService/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:xsd1="http://www.cisco.com/AXL/API/8.0" targetNamespace="http://www.cisco.com/AXLAPIService/">
<import location="AXLSoap.xsd" namespace="http://www.cisco.com/AXL/API/8.0"/>
<message name="addSipProfileIn">
<part element="xsd1:addSipProfile" name="axlParams"/>
</message>
```

First few lines of AXLSoap.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.cisco.com/AXL/API/8.0" xmlns:axlapi="http://www.cisco.com/AXL/API/8.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="unqualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="8.0">
<xsd:complexType name='XSipProfile'>
<xsd:sequence minOccurs='0'>
<xsd:element maxOccurs='1' nillable='false' name='name' minOccurs='1' type='axlapi:String50'></xsd:element>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938443/schema-has-to-begin-with-a-schema-element-in-namespace-http-www-w3-org-200

Comment: What do the first few lines of AXLSoap.xsd look like?

Comment: JLRishe: just added the AXLSoap.xsd opening lines

Comment: Also - the same xml/xsd produce perfect .cs proxy code when used with the wsdl.exe tool. And the service gives expected results when called via that code. It's just the Visual Studio 2010 shell for SSIS that is giving the above error.

Comment: I found this documented bug, but the example provided is too complex for me.

[http://support.microsoft.com/kb/820122?wa=wsignin1.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/820122?wa=wsignin1.0)

I'm almost positive my error might be related to the bug, because even if I change the location property in <import> element of wsdl to a random filename, I get the same error. Any ideas anyone??

Comment: The link at 'http://support.microsoft.com/kb/820122?wa=wsignin1.0' above leads to a Page Not Found error.

Answer (score 3):

turned out to be that the  element in XSD expects a fully qualified (http or https, cannot be c:\ d:\ relative etc.) location property. Once I uploaded the xsd to a web server and pointed the location property to that, voila!